# Does implicit wait in selenium, only used for element search?

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium, testng, load-testing

I wanted to understand the usage of implicit wait in selenium.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Will it be used only for element search or for any other purpose like for page load and refresh? As usual, I am using this in the beginning of driver initialization.

But in my application I want to inspect error message after entering the wrong password, but as soon as I enter the wrong password, it will leave the page and will not wait for the error message on the same page. Will it initialize/load the page only once?. When I use Thread.sleep(3) it stops at the page for 3 secs and also properly reads the error message.

But I don't want to use Thread.sleep, since I am already using implicit wait.

Can anyone please tell me its use and how do I resolve this error?

Code Snippet below:(Not Working,returning FAILURE)
(Without Thread.sleep)

```
 setText(WebElements.TEXT_BOX, PASSWORD);
    click(WebElements.SUBMIT_BUTTON);
           //Thread.sleep(3000);
            if (isElementPresent(WebElements.ERROR_MESSAGE)) {
                          return SUCCESS;
      }
            else 
                    return FAILURE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between the *Implicit* and *Explicit* waits is that the Implicit wait polls the *DOM* for a defined amount of time(let's say 10s) and looks for the element whereas Explicit wait periodically sends the request to the server and check for the element in DOM.

The Implicit wait is firm and fixed to the driver instance. So, once you set that time it is set for the entire driver instance and applied everywhere. With that in place, when you use any command to find an element it polls the DOM for that defined amount of time **without talking to the server/sending another request** periodically and finally throws an exception if nothing found.

On the other hand, *Explicit* wait has a [default time](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/6b4e6de722fcccd18619951543143999e9a30657/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.java) of 500ms sleeps in it unless you explicitly override that. Meaning it acts as `Thread.sleep();` in between the intervals and sleeps for 500ms and after that sends the request to the server and periodically checks for the element and conditions you defined with a polling interval defined and reaches the timeout.

So, in your case the `Thread.Sleep()` is working as *Explicit* wait. The proper resolutions is of course to use *Explicit* wait and periodically checks for the element and it's expected condition.

```
setText(WebElements.TEXT_BOX, PASSWORD);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);

try{

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("id of the element to be located")));
    return SUCCESS;
}
catch (NoSuchElementException exception)
{
    return FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First you do some click. Then teh page changes. Before you call isElementPresent(), how will you know, if the page has already loaded?

Better would be not to use implicitlyWait() and not sleep(). Use FluentWait:
https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html

FluentWait periodically checks, if your condition is "true". If not (e.g. if the page is not yet loaded completely), waits some time and checks again.

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you to use explicit wait as given below

```
int wait = 10;
WebDriverWait WAIT = new WebDriverWait(driver,wait);
try{
    WAIT.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("id of element")));
    return SUCCESS;
}
catch (NoSuchElementException exception)
{
    return FAILURE;
}
```

difference between Difference Between Implicit, Explicit & Fluent Wait you can find [here](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implicit-explicit-n-fluent-wait/)